Various issues with uploading large files to S3 via Strapi
I'm running an installation of Strapi v5.1.1 on an Ubuntu v24.10 server with Nginx 1.26. The Strapi app uses an S3 bucket for media file storage, and a MySQL database, hosted on a DigitalOcean Droplet.
I've been having trouble uploading large files to the Strapi app - the issues started at around 256MBs, and I've knocked a few errors out with various config fixes, including the solutions in Node.js: what is ENOSPC error and how to solve? and ENOSPC no space left on device -Nodejs. Those attempts are detailed below.
(This is a very long question, but I think it's worth it to document everything in detail here because I'm compiling about a week's worth of googling and problem-solving across multiple different issues. Hopefully this can be helpful to someone else.)
Currently I have a file that's 1.85GBs, which I'm having trouble uploading. On my local dev environment (just running npm run develop on my Mac), it works fine - the file uploads, it displays, I can log into AWS and see it sitting there, no prob. But, on production, my pm2 logs give the following error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, write. The largest file I'll want to upload currently is about 4.5GBs, but let's say I might want to go as high as 10GBs in the future.
The issues started at around 256MB files, and these various solutions have gotten me as far as this point:

I've made a number of config changes to my Strapi app. Probably some of these are redundant or don't do anything, but combined, they seem to have ironed out any Strapi-specific issues (so far).

config/middlewares.ts
name: "strapi::body",
config: {
  formLimit: "1024mb", // modify form body
  jsonLimit: "1024mb", // modify JSON body
  textLimit: "1024mb", // modify text body
  enabled: true,
  multipart: true,
  formidable: {
    maxFileSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
  },
},


config/plugins.ts
upload: {
  config: {
    sizeLimit: 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
    enabled: true,
    multipart: true,
  },
},


config/server.ts
bootstrap({ strapi }) {
  strapi.server.httpServer.requestTimeout = 30 * 60 * 1000;
},


config/uploads.ts
export default {
  upload: {
    config: {
      sizeLimit: 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, // 1GB in bytes
      enabled: true,
      multipart: true,
    },
  },
};


src/index.ts
bootstrap({ strapi }) {
  strapi.server.httpServer.requestTimeout = 30 * 60 * 1000;
},




I've switched from hosting the Strapi app on DigitalOcean's App Platform over to a Droplet. I filed a support ticket about a 413 Request Entity Too Large error I was getting, and they informed me that all the App Platform traffic goes through Cloudflare, which has a 500MB limit, which is probably what I was hitting. Switching over to a Droplet and configuring Nginx seems to have gotten me past that 500MB limit.

I made a number of config changes to nginx.conf.
http {
  client_max_body_size 10240M;
  proxy_request_buffering off;
  proxy_read_timeout 300;
  proxy_connect_timeout 300;
  proxy_send_timeout 300;
}


I've increased the sysctls fs.inotify.max_user_instances, fs.inotify.max_user_watches, and max_queued_events by a lot. I don't totally know what these numbers represent (files?), so it's possible I've set them to something dangerous - or not? In any case, I ran the following commands:

sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=2097152
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_queued_events=2097152
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=2097152
sudo sysctl -p


Finally, I made sure the error I was getting didn't reflect the hard drive actually running out of space. Running df -kh . | tail -n1 | awk '{print $4}' (to give me the amount of free space on the disk) returns 19G - well within the safe amount for uploading a ~2GB file.


Producing the current issue:
While uploading this large file, I'm setting a timer to help with watching for potential timeout issues, plus I'm monitoring my outgoing bandwidth, plus I have the browser console open to watch for errors, plus I also have some consoles open and monitoring these four logs:

/var/log/nginx/access.log
/var/log/nginx/error.log
~/.pm2/logs/strapi-out.log
~/.pm2/logs/strapi-error.log

I get a few different errors at different times, which seem to be related to each other. I'll try and articulate the timing and my interpretation of each here:

I start a timer and begin the upload.
At around 1:00, ~/.pm2/logs/strapi-out.log returns:
[2024-10-26 18:10:23.773] error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
[2024-10-26 18:10:23.773] http: POST /upload (58219 ms) 500

At the same time, /var/log/nginx/error.log returns 2024/10/26 18:10:23 [error] 877#877: *417 writev() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream
Curiously, the browser doesn't produce an error at this point, and my outgoing bandwidth indicates that I'm still sending the file.
At around 2:15, ~/.pm2/logs/strapi-out.log again returns the same output as above. Maybe it got the error once and then re-tried sending the file? Curiously, ~/.pm2/logs/strapi-error.log returns nothing yet.
Finally at around 2:45, the browser returns a 500 error. and /var/log/nginx/access.log returns "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "https://...

Conclusions so far

This doesn't seem to be an issue with Strapi, as I can upload the file just fine from my local environment, with the app started in development mode.
This doesn't seem to be an issue with actual hard drive space.
This doesn't seem to be an issue with max_user_instances, max_user_watches, or max_queued_events. (Unless I'm underestimating how high I should set these numbers.)
This doesn't seem to be an (easily googlable) issue with Nginx, from what I've gleaned.

Thanks for reading all this, any ideas would be appreciated!
Update 1
It's still not working on prod, but I realized that I'd only tested uploads on my local environment up to about 800MBs, so I gave it a try with this 1.85GB file, and found that it wasn't working.
I realized that in my Strapi config files, I had to change the three instances of 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 to 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 (duh). This got things working on my local again - great! However, it's still not working on prod. That said, I at least get a couple different errors now.

strapi-out.log returns the same ENOSPC: no space left on device, write error.
/var/log/nginx/error.log also returns the same [error] 877#877: *545 writev() failed (32: Broken pipe) while sending request to upstream
The browser window displays the Strapi error "An error occurred while uploading the file."
And, the browser's console displays a few errors that look like maybe the upload was cut off - not very informative at first glance, but maybe there's something I'm missing:


Update 2
I've discovered that Strapi is storing files in /tmp, rather than ~/project-name/.tmp, as I previously assumed. I found this out by running df -h a few times during the upload process, and watching the output change like this:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           984M     0  984M   0% /tmp

... to ...
tmpfs           984M   71M  913M   8% /tmp

... and ...
tmpfs           984M  152M  832M  16% /tmp

... and so on. This looks very promising as the current issue. I can see /tmp appears to be a separate partition, with 984MBs allotted to it, and this checks out with the behavior I've been seeing - files <1GB seem to be fine, and files >1GB won't work.
After reading this thread, it seems like the next fix is to increase the partition size of /tmp. I've done this by using the sudo systemctl edit tmp.mount --full command, and editing this line:
Options=mode=1777,strictatime,nosuid,nodev,size=11G,nr_inodes=1m

This gets me further than before, but it seems that the file is simultaneously being stored in memory? I'm seeing a spike in memory at the time of uploading, and once the upload gets to about 1.5GBs, the server freezes up and needs to restart (it has 2GBs of memory total).
I can increase the memory of the server to 4 GBs and re-upload the same file, and it works (!). But, if I want to have a maximum of 10GBs, it seems like there should be a better way to accomplish this.
The current question
Must the files that I'm uploading to S3, via Strapi, be written to /tmp and memory at the same time? I've already configured Strapi for multipart uploads, so I'm not sure if / how to configure it further. Might there be a further configuration that I'd make to the provider-upload-aws-s3 plugin that I'm using?
I can see multiple closed issues related to this on github (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), so it's curious that I'm still experiencing this.

ENOSPC no space left on device -Nodejs ??

This question is similar to: Node.js: what is ENOSPC error and how to solve?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@TobySpeight It looks like this question is suggesting the solution of altering fs.inotify.max_user_watches, which I mentioned I tried already. I scrolled through the other solutions in the question but didn't see anything I've not tried already.
